# Login to WebForm using Powershell

Tags: powershell, authentication, webforms, invoke-command

I've been trying for a while to Login to a site, navigate through it and download file at conditions. I've tried with PhantomJs but failed miserably.

Now I'm trying with a Powershell approach and I've been looking around to how get the first step, logging into the the form to get to the next page.

The last site I've followed the hints was [PowerShell Getting Started](http://www.gngrninja.com/script-ninja/2016/7/8/powershell-getting-started-utilizing-the-web#downloadfile) the very last topic "Logging In To Web Sites"

The site which I'm trying to log in: [ACSMAMGA](http://portal.reti.acsm-agam.it/Portal/Index.aspx?idn=0005&area=B2B)

It's seems a very easy login form, so I setp up the powershell code like this:

```
#Input User and Password - Set UserAgent - Store the WebRequest

 $credential = Get-Credential
 $uaString   = [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PSUserAgent]::FireFox
 $webRequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://portal.reti.acsm-agam.it/Portal/Index.aspx?m=200G&area=B2B' -SessionVariable webSession -UserAgent $uaString

#Store the form with id 'form1' into variable - Set fields of the form with the credential inputted before

 $loginForm= $webRequest.Forms | Where-Object {$_.Id -eq 'form1'}
 $loginForm.Fields.twsTemplate_Content1_twsModule_txtUser   = $credential.UserName
 $loginForm.Fields.twsTemplate_Content1_twsModule_txtPSW = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password

#Set New Request with new data, I change the -uri $loginform.action to the actual site because it actually set it to Index.aspx?m=200G&area=B2B which is just the last part of the actual site "http://portal.reti.acsm-agam.it/Portal/Index.aspx?m=200G&area=B2B" and it will raise an error

 $webRequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $loginForm.Action -Method $loginForm.Method -Body $loginForm.Fields -WebSession $webSession -UserAgent $uaString

#Check if login has been successfuf,changed the Where-Object statment to an actual element that can be found in page that get showed after loggin in.

if ($webRequest.Links | Where-Object {$_.id -like ('*' + "twsTemplate_Header1_LogOff1_LnkLOF" + '*')}) {

    Write-Host "Login verified!"

} else {

    Write-Host 'Login unsuccessful!' -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor DarkBlue

}
```

Ofcourse the If Statement return "Login unsuccessful".

There might be something else in the login page that get involved after sending the request.
I've noted there are some input fields that are hidden (I guess they are some token, dunno how those things work) and 3 javascript running in background but dunno what they do and I read they are wrapper for function or such).

Would be great if anyone can take down this. It's long time i've been trying to automate the access to those type of sites.
Thank you

Edit:08.06.2017
HI've been doing some more test.
It seems that the problemi that it's blocking me to get to next page after the login is how the inputfields are passed.
Actually usgin:

```
 $loginForm.Fields.twsTemplate_Content1_twsModule_txtUser   = $credential.UserName
 $loginForm.Fields.twsTemplate_Content1_twsModule_txtPSW = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
```

Dont' work, instead passing the same value but like

```
$loginForm.Fields['twsTemplate$Content1$twsModule$txtUser']= $credential.UserName
     $loginForm.Fields['twsTemplate$Content1$twsModule$txtPSW'] = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
```

get the work done (note the "$" instead of "_" and the "'" that wrap the name or the $ would be treated as variable.
I even had to add "twsTemplate_Content1_twsModule_btnLogin Login" which is already setted in the page but still I have to convert the "_" with "$" and set the value as above.

I don't get why this work but actually worked ...

edit 17.07.2017
I should have know before but I get on the programmin subject only in spare time as it not my work. Those field with the "$" work as in the post method you have to pass the name attribute of the field, which in my case are those with the $.

Comment: `$webResponse` instead of `$webRequest` may be a better variable name. What is the content of the response?

Comment: Thanks for the advise about the variable name. Actually the web request content is the same as the login page. Like I was redirected to the same page and nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

So this uses the post information and signs in if you have the correct login.
It also brings back a Session so you can keep interacting with the site.

```
function Login([string]$Address,[pscredential]$credential){
    if(!$credential){
        $credential = Get-Credential
    }
    $post = "__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=%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%2BMa9cyFCJx8l%2BEYykopVYA0gwPUz3FbFyI0NAU1WC&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=DF200D8E&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWBAK8z%2BQMAsaPwpsGAqnL470LAq%2F5qKcIp5vlm7cytSxOzkYL2ESDraZWLoQRji0OxUOW9t%2FXBRI%3D&smRetiWeb=&twsTemplate%24Content1%24twsModule%24txtUser=$($credential.GetNetworkCredential().UserName)&twsTemplate%24Content1%24twsModule%24txtPSW=$($credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password)&twsTemplate%24Content1%24twsModule%24btnLogin=Login"
    $Information = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Address -Method POST -Body $Post -SessionVariable WebSession
    return $WebSession
}

login -Address "http://portal.reti.acsm-agam.it/Portal/Index.aspx?idn=0005&area=B2B"
```

Comment: This actually give back this :
Headers: {}
Cookies: System.Net.CookieContainer
UseDefaultCredentials : False
Credentials : 
Certificates : 
UserAgent : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT; Windows NT 10.0; it-IT) WindowsPowerShell/5.1.14393.1198
Proxy:
MaximumRedirection : -1
How to I know If i've succesful entere the login ? And where you find the viewstate parameter you entered ? I just download fiddler to check network traffic and I guess you take it from there, but I have to know it dynamically cause there are like 10 login sites like this and I guess the viewstate change.

Comment: yes, thats the websession not the webresponse.

The websession allows u to keep the connection to the website and do more webrequests as that user, using the -Websession option.

If you want to view the Response view the $Information Varable.

Also i take it from Chrome or IE developer tools.....just hit F12 to see them.

Comment: I run the function but I dunno what to do after ... If I set another WebRequest with same address/method/post/ but with the -Websession $websession option (return from your function) when I store the response in the variable and do $respone.content it display the html of the login page. The $information variable cannot be reused as it dies after the function end.

Comment: Did some tries and I'm sorry but the function you build seems just to do the same thing as my script with the difference that the viewstate value you provided is (according to chrome dev tool) the same I enter but not parsed (it parse the "/" to %2F and maybe some other special character)

Comment: LOL if i had a login I could figure it out :) (sadly I dont understand what you mean to do after)